# How to store code metrics results from an automated TFS 2010 Build, to a database

Tags: tfsbuild

I wanted to know if there is a out-of-the-box feature/solution in TFS 2010 to have the results of code metrics and code coverage stored in a database or a folder location? If not, can this be achieved by a custom built component or job and get that executed as part of the build using BuildScript so that it picks these results and does what we want to do? In this case, may be pick the old metrics results XML file and compare it with the latest results XML?

I am looking at having these results in SQL Server (only for code metrics, code analysis statistics and code coverage and not the entire build report) and later use it via SSRS for reporting. The ultimate aim is to have a progressive check on the code quality, during every build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2011/01/30/integrating-code-metrics-in-tfs-2010-build.aspx) has details about integrating code metrics with TFS Build. Build does not have a built-in solution for code metrics, so to store your code metrics in the database, you will need to store them as a custom build information field in order to display them in your build report or compare them with other builds.

Code coverage IS supported out of the box with TFS Build. This [post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/06/14/running-code-coverage-in-tfs2010-builds/) described how to enable it.

Comment: Thanks Duat. I lately figured out the Custom Build Activity could be used for code metrics.